# Quick sign-in to Google Sites for Google Apps for Education?

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites

My university has Google Sites that are in its own domain ([Google Apps for Education](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/education/)). At the bottom of a **regular** Google Sites page there is usually the following set of links:

```
Sign in|Report Abuse|Print Page|Remove Access|Powered By Google Sites
```

However, with the Education version of Google Sites, there is no `Sign in` link:

```
Report Abuse|Print Page|Remove Access|Powered By Google Sites
```

Does anyone know why this is different and/or how to achieve a quick sign-in? The work-around is to sign in to my Google Apps for Education Gmail (which my school doesn't use yet) and then navigate back to the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're the site owner, then you're able to check if the footer can show the sign-in option.

Go to the site and press the key combination <kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>m</kbd> or choose from the **more** pull-down menu of the *Manage site* option. Then select site layout:
[image]

Followed by **system footer**:
[image]

If the sign-in option is ticked, then it will not show:
[image]

Comment: The word "admin" is vague here... there's a site owner and then there's the "admin" for the entire domain. In fact, I found out that as the site owner I can modify the system footer. I think that is what you meant in this answer? I think the site configuration overrides the domain configuration.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator That's what I meant. Thanks for clearing that. Feel free to edit the answer. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I found another way that seems to work without being admin. The sign-in URL that appears in non-Education sites looks like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/AddSession?service=jotspot&continue=SITEURL
```

where `SITEURL` is the URL of the page you want to edit (via sign in).

So, I hacked the URL to put the `SITEURL` of the page I tend to edit a lot. Then I saved the URL as a bookmark.

There's probably a way to do this as a marklet, too...